# Access USB pendrive from Windows service

Tags: windows, usb-flash-drive, windows-services

there is a way from a Windows service to detect when a pendrive usb is inserted and write a file to it?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using Task Scheduler?

Comment: Uh? I cannot figure out how to do

Comment: That's fine. I can't really help you right now, i'll try later

Comment: [How to Start your Windows Service When a USB Flash Drive is Inserted](https://www.coretechnologies.com/blog/service-trigger-editor/start-windows-service-usb-flash-drive/)

Comment: Very nice ServiceTrigger, but my question was simpler: if a user is not logged, where is mounted a pendrive? Can I access through a drive letter?